# Are Cavalier-Poodle able to run over 2km?

Tags: dogs, health

My wife and I are thinking about adopting a 2.5 year old cavapoo (50% Cavalier- 50% miniature Poodle 8.5kg).

**Scenario**

I have a very large office at work and am thinking I could take the dog with me to work everyday. I work at 2km from home and am biking everyday on concrete path that would be safe for a dog to run next to the bike (except if the concrete would hurt the dog's paws). The trip is mainly flat and I take about 4-5 minutes to make it but I realize I will have to slow down for the dog. Intuitively, I'd think that such a trip would be too enduring for such a relatively small dog but I might be mistaken as I have little experience with dogs (and even less with small dogs).

**Question**

- Is an adult cavapoo able to run over 2km on concrete twice a day?
- How much time would it take to a cavapoo to run over 2km?
- I live at Vancouver, BC. The temperature does not get too high but the winter is very rainy. Will the dog be happy to run under the rain?

I could also take the cavapoo in a bucket in the morning and allow it to run on the way back in the evening, or systematically take the cavapoo in the bucket for half the trip. Does one of these alternative sounds like a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think a dog that small could keep up with a bicycle, and would have trouble keeping up with a jogger for that distance. Dogs from the herding and sporting groups tend to make better running companions because running is part of the "job" of their breed. But realize that no dog is really bred to run long distances continuously -- they are bred to run in bursts.

Your dog is the product of two toy breeds, who were originally bred just to be companion dogs. Running isn't in their genes. A small dog will have to take several steps just to match one of your strides. Trying to keep up with a bicycle seems impossible.

Comment: You might be able to mount a pet carrier on the bicycle, if you want to bring the dog with you. (I've transported cats that way.) Or modify a child trailer for the purpose.

Comment: Just as a follow-up if you are curious. We ended up adopting a Cockapoo (Cocker spaniel - poodle) that was just born in the neighboorhood. He can run up to 45km/h and, on a non-paved road, he very much able to keep up with a bike for a good 6 km if needed. He hates the rain though and prefer finding shelters (he is off-leash) rather than following the bike when it rains.